# To rotation an image in canvas using mouse

Tags: javascript, rotation, html5-canvas

In my code I am loading an image in to a canvas. Then I need to resize, rotate and drag it. I managed to implement both dragging and resizing.

How can I implement rotation(along the center of the image) using mouse on this code.

**My HTML page:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px;}
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var startX;
    var startY;
    var isDown=false;


    var pi2=Math.PI*2;
    var resizerRadius=8;
    var rr=resizerRadius*resizerRadius;
    var draggingResizer={x:0,y:0};
    var imageX=50;
    var imageY=50;
    var imageWidth,imageHeight,imageRight,imageBottom;
    var draggingImage=false;
    var startX;
    var startY;



    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        imageWidth=img.width;
        imageHeight=img.height;
        imageRight=imageX+imageWidth;
        imageBottom=imageY+imageHeight
        draw(true,false);
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/facesSmall.png";


    function draw(withAnchors,withBorders){

        // clear the canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        // draw the image
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,imageX,imageY,imageWidth,imageHeight);

        // optionally draw the draggable anchors
        if(withAnchors){
            drawDragAnchor(imageX,imageY);
            drawDragAnchor(imageRight,imageY);
            drawDragAnchor(imageRight,imageBottom);
            drawDragAnchor(imageX,imageBottom);
        }

        // optionally draw the connecting anchor lines
        if(withBorders){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(imageX,imageY);
            ctx.lineTo(imageRight,imageY);
            ctx.lineTo(imageRight,imageBottom);
            ctx.lineTo(imageX,imageBottom);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }

    }

    function drawDragAnchor(x,y){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,resizerRadius,0,pi2,false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }

    function anchorHitTest(x,y){

        var dx,dy;

        // top-left
        dx=x-imageX;
        dy=y-imageY;
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<=rr){ return(0); }
        // top-right
        dx=x-imageRight;
        dy=y-imageY;
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<=rr){ return(1); }
        // bottom-right
        dx=x-imageRight;
        dy=y-imageBottom;
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<=rr){ return(2); }
        // bottom-left
        dx=x-imageX;
        dy=y-imageBottom;
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<=rr){ return(3); }
        return(-1);

    }


    function hitImage(x,y){
        return(x>imageX && x<imageX+imageWidth && y>imageY && y<imageY+imageHeight);
    }


    function handleMouseDown(e){
      startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      draggingResizer=anchorHitTest(startX,startY);
      draggingImage= draggingResizer<0 && hitImage(startX,startY);
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      draggingResizer=-1;
      draggingImage=false;
      draw(true,false);
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      handleMouseUp(e);
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){

      if(draggingResizer>-1){

          mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
          mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

          // resize the image
          switch(draggingResizer){
              case 0: //top-left
                  imageX=mouseX;
                  imageWidth=imageRight-mouseX;
                  imageY=mouseY;
                  imageHeight=imageBottom-mouseY;
                  break;
              case 1: //top-right
                  imageY=mouseY;
                  imageWidth=mouseX-imageX;
                  imageHeight=imageBottom-mouseY;
                  break;
              case 2: //bottom-right
                  imageWidth=mouseX-imageX;
                  imageHeight=mouseY-imageY;
                  break;
              case 3: //bottom-left
                  imageX=mouseX;
                  imageWidth=imageRight-mouseX;
                  imageHeight=mouseY-imageY;
                  break;
          }

          // enforce minimum dimensions of 25x25
          if(imageWidth<25){imageWidth=25;}
          if(imageHeight<25){imageHeight=25;}

          // set the image right and bottom
          imageRight=imageX+imageWidth;
          imageBottom=imageY+imageHeight;

          // redraw the image with resizing anchors
          draw(true,true);

      }else if(draggingImage){

          imageClick=false;

          mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
          mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

          // move the image by the amount of the latest drag
          var dx=mouseX-startX;
          var dy=mouseY-startY;
          imageX+=dx;
          imageY+=dy;
          imageRight+=dx;
          imageBottom+=dy;
          // reset the startXY for next time
          startX=mouseX;
          startY=mouseY;

          // redraw the image with border
          draw(false,true);

      }


    }


    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Resize the image using the 4 draggable corner anchors</p>
    <p>You can also drag the image</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Here’s how to use a drag-handle to rotate an image**

[image][image]

**The mousedown event handler hit-tests if the user is starting to drag the rotation-handle.**

This hit-testing is made easier with context.isPointInPath(x,y) which tests whether a specified [x,y] coordinate is inside the most recently drawn path (Conveniently, the rotation-handle is actually a path).

So mousedown activates the drag-handle like this:

- Calculate the current mouseX and mouseY.
- Redraw the rotation handle (required because isPointInPath hit-tests just the most recent path)
- Set the isDown flag if the user did click in the rotation handle.

The mousedown code looks like this:

```
function handleMouseDown(e){
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  drawRotationHandle(false);
  isDown=ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY);
}
```

Yes...we could have simply hit-tested a circle on the end of the rotation-handle, but using isPointInPath will allow you to draw whatever fancy rotation handle you desire.

And isPointInPath has another nice benefit.  When the context containing the path is rotated, isPointInPath will hit-test the **rotated path** for you.  This means you don't have to code the math to unrotate the mouse coordinates to do the hit testing--it's done for you!

**The mousemove handler redraws the rotatable image at the angle specified by the rotation-handle:**

- If the isDown flag is not set, just return (the user is not dragging the rotation-handle).
- Calculate the current mouseX and mouseY.
- Calculate the current angle of the rotation-handle.
- Redraw the rotatable image at the current angle.

The mousemove code looks like this:

```
function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  var dx=mouseX-cx;
  var dy=mouseY-cy;
  r=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
  draw();
}
```

**The image is drawn at the specified rotation using context's transform methods**

```
function drawRect(){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx,cy);
    ctx.rotate(r);
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

**Finally, the mouseup and mouseout handlers stop the drag operation by clearing the isDown flag.**

```
function handleMouseUp(e){
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
  isDown=false;
}
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/QqwKR/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var isDown=false;

    var cx=canvas.width/2;
    var cy=canvas.height/2;
    var w;
    var h;
    var r=0;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        w=img.width/2;
        h=img.height/2;
        draw();
    }
    img.src="facesSmall.png";


    function draw(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        drawRotationHandle(true);
        drawRect();
    }

    function drawRect(){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(cx,cy);
        ctx.rotate(r);
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,-w/2,-h/2,w,h);
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function drawRotationHandle(withFill){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(cx,cy);
        ctx.rotate(r);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0,-1);
        ctx.lineTo(w/2+20,-1);
        ctx.lineTo(w/2+20,-7);
        ctx.lineTo(w/2+30,-7);
        ctx.lineTo(w/2+30,7);
        ctx.lineTo(w/2+20,7);
        ctx.lineTo(w/2+20,1);
        ctx.lineTo(0,1);
        ctx.closePath();
        if(withFill){
            ctx.fillStyle="blue";
            ctx.fill();
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      drawRotationHandle(false);
      isDown=ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY);
      console.log(isDown);
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      if(!isDown){return;}

      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      var dx=mouseX-cx;
      var dy=mouseY-cy;
      r=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
      draw();
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Rotate by dragging blue rotation handle</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank for awesome answer, @markE ! But I have small problem. My canvas has background (drawn an image on it), when I add "facesSmall.png" by `draw()`, `ctx.clearRect()` make canvas to be white blank. How to keep image I drawn before?

Comment: You're welcome.  If you have a background image, just drawImage that image right after each clearRect. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, I get it now! It's is simple solution!

Comment: Awesome, but I have problem:( How to use shear mapping to modification an image? Example: http://fabricjs.com/matrix-transformation/

Comment: @Piotr. You would need to post that as a new question because it is off-topic to this Q&A. :-)

Comment: That's right. It was my act of desperation because I sit on it a few days:( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922237/skew-the-drawing-horizontally-and-vertically-in-html5-canvas-using-mouse

Comment: Hi! How can this example be adjusted to work for multiple images? It's not about the multiple images, but how can I find out which drag-handle belongs to which image?

Comment: Can you add to include corner points being drawn?