# rotate and change image in canvas javascript

Tags: image, rotation, html5-canvas

[image]

I want do something like [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229319/to-rotation-an-image-in-html5-canvas-using-mouse) but a more advanced version of that..

I want to also change image when mouse drag distance is not in some user defined range than want to change image in canvas, check if mouse move point is between those two circles (not less or greater).

Comment: I am using plugin from http://spritespin.ginie.eu/ to achieve like this http://truview.ortery.com/HTMLJavaScript/FlowerRing/HTML5Viewer.html but not have any success

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are asking. Please specify exactly where you are stuck. Explain what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what happens instead. Post the relevant code you wrote.

Comment: if mouse drag  in circular range then rotate that perticluar image in canvas by drag position else change image source,,here in else part i am using plugin spritespin.ginie.eu.

Comment: updated my question ,please see image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide code in your question, so here is a non-code answer:

You can use Math.atan2 to get the angle of the mouseclick and apply that same angle to your image.

You can use pythagora's theorm to determine the distance from the click to the image center. Then test if that distance is between your 2 circles' radii.