# Rotate image interactively

Tags: html, rotation, interactive, rotatetransform

is it possible to rotate an image by mouse-click? So I´m having an image on an empty html-page and want to click and drag the image, so that it rotates around it´s center.
Do you have a code or working example?

Best regards,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using java script.Following is just a sample code.

```
<style type="text/css">
  img.primary   { display: inline; }
  img.secondary { display: none; }
  div.foo:hover img.secondary { display: inline; }
  div.foo:hover img.primary   { display: none; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function swapImages(container)
{
    for(var child in container.childNodes)
    {
        child = container.childNodes[child];
        if(child.nodeName == "IMG")
            child.className = child.className == "primary" ?
                "secondary" : "primary";
    }   
}

window.onload = function() {
    // Remove the foo class when the page loads, to disable hover
    var chartArea = document.getElementById("chartArea");
    for(var child in chartArea.childNodes)
    {
        child = chartArea.childNodes[child];
        if(child.nodeName == "DIV" && child.className == "foo")
            child.className = "";
    }
}
</script>

<div id="chartArea">
    <div class="foo" onclick="swapImages(this);">
        <img class="primary" src="http://somewhere/piechart1.png" />
        <img class="secondary" src="http://somewhere/barchart1.png" />
   </div>

    <div class="foo" onclick="swapImages(this);">
        <img class="primary" ... />
        <img class="secondary" ... />    
    </div>

   <div class="foo" ....>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but that´s not that what I´ve searched. I don´t want to swap the image but rotate it. So just one image and with click and drag I want to rotate it like its a steering wheel of a car which I wanna rotate.

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229319/to-rotation-an-image-in-html5-canvas-using-mouse) u might be looking for this