# Skew the drawing horizontally and vertically in html5 canvas using mouse

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

In my code I am loading images to canvas element. Then I need to drag, resize, rotate and **skew** it. I managed to implement both dragging and resizing. How can I implement skew using mouse on this code? I read a helpful article on this subject (http://www.subshell.com/en/subshell/blog/image-manipulation-html5-canvas102.html). I found fabricjs plugin, but it work only one image and without drag. For example: http://fabricjs.com/matrix-transformation/ .
If you will use the transform function:

```
ctx.transform(1, 0.5, -0.5, 1.2, 30, 60);
```

This will transform all image objects assigned to the canvas element. I would like only the selected image.

My code:

https://jsfiddle.net/sjLnqk5d/2/

Comment: Maybe use `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()`?

Comment: It will not change anything. The `transform` function refers to all contents. So if I would like to use the transform to skew I have to create canvas element to image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjLnqk5d/3/) that allows you to skew any image individually by pressing Shift when clicking one of the corner handles. You may need to tweak it a little bit to have the movements appear a bit more intuitive.

The trick is indeed in using `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` around the `ctx.transform()` call, which makes sure that the transformation (and any other property changes) only applies between the `save` and `restore`.

Here are the key changes:

`Shape.prototype.draw`:

```
...
var skewX = this.skewX;
var skewY = this.skewY;
imgNew.onload = function(){ 
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform(1, skewX/100, skewY/100, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(imgNew, locx, locy, width, height);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: Good job! Thank you very much. How do I calculate the squares on the corners for the picture after skew transform?

Comment: That's a bit [complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix). You'll need to multiply your corner coordinate vector with the 3x3 transformation Matrix. But if you can tweak the `/100` so that the mouse coordinate matches the corner of the image then you can simply add the `skewX` and `skewY` to the corner squares.

Comment: @Kenney. upvote. yep, save & restore will do the job. They will save and restore the entire context state (transforms, stylings, compositings, etc). It's slightly more efficient to just reset just the transforms to their default state (no transformations) using `context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`. ;-)